# No puedo conectarme a la base de datos en localhost en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero ejecutar este código con php, que es conectarme a mysql. Tengo este código:

```js
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contrasenia = '';
$bd = 'banco';

try{
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=bd",$usuario, $contrasenia);
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Conexión establecida";
} catch(PDOException $error){
    echo "Conexión erronea <br>" . $error;
}
?>
```

¿Qué me recomienda que haga?
pero al intentar conectarme me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$bd",$usuario, $contrasenia);`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asegúrate de tener conexión a tu servidor de base de datos
Si estás trabajando con XAMPP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entra al Shell y coloca `mysql -u root -p` te solicitara la contraseña, si no has configurado ninguna solo da `Enter`, si puedes acceder quiere decir que el usuario root si existe y tiene conexión, de lo contrario tendrias que ver la configuración de usuarios, o que le hayas asignado una contraseña.

Comment: Sí, esa parte si la comprendo y he entrado. No tengo errores en ese aspecto.

Comment: Solo se me ocurre verificar la configuración de los puertos, que este configurado en el 3306 en los archivos `my.ini y php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error de sintaxis aquí:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=bd",$usuario, $contrasenia);
```

Tendrías que también pasar el parámetro de la base de datos a tu conexión, quedando así:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contrasenia = '';
$bd = 'banco';

try{
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$bd",$usuario, $contrasenia);
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Conexión establecida";
  } catch(PDOException $error){
    echo "Conexión erronea <br>" . $error;
  }
?>
```

Comment: No amigo, sigue fallando :(

Comment: Te aseguraste que tus credenciales para conectarte son correctas? Qué error te sale?

Comment: Tengo todo bien. Mi usuario es root y no tengo contraseña

Comment: Mmm que extraño... pero qué error te sale? quisiera saber...

Comment: Ese es el problema, no me sale ningún tipo de error ni nada. Cero advertencia. Lo que no sé si tenga algo que ver con el puerto. El mio es 3307. Ya que el original es el 3306.

Comment: Verificaste que estás en la página del archivo donde haces la conexión? no se me ocurre otra cosa, si fuese el puerto recibirías error...

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a las dos personas que estuvieron al pendiente de mi problema. Ya lo pude resolver. Era el puerto. Curiosamente hace tiempo lo tuve que cambiar a 3307 porque el 3306 me daba problemas. Ahora, al probar con el puerto 3306 de nuevo, ya pude hacer la conexión.

Los consejos que me daban aquí funcionaban para corrobar si todo estaba en orden, estaba muy bien, pero nomás no daban. Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.